# Use Where Clause in @OneToMany JPA Collection

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to implement historical records using the first solution suggested [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105768/Audit-Trail-Tracing-Data-Changes-in-Database).

In my project, we have routes, stops, children, and records of when each child arrived at a stop.

When the stop time is updated, I want the records to still be related to that stop, but use the time that the stop had at creation.

The only problem I have so far is that with Hibernate, is that when fetching a route's stops, I want to ignore stops marked historic.

Can I configure @OneToMany collection in route to only fetch stops by using a where clause?

Comment: See https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-where-clause for an example of the Hibernate specific `@Where` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

No, [`@OneToMany`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html) just indicates the static entity relationship that underneath the hood is translated into foreign keys etc., together with some hints about eager/lazy retrieval, cascading of updates/deletes.

What you need for your case is to create a `@NamedQuery` which takes a `where` clause. It uses JPQL, so you will still be interacting with your object model.

Since you are using `spring-data` you could also use a repository method, assuming you have a `RouteRepository` or `StopRepository`, where you get the non-historic `Stop`s for your `Route`.

You haven't included any code examples so I can't provide much more detail than that.

Comment: I plan on moving to NamedQuerys soon to remove eager fetching throughout the application. For the meantime I've found @Filter, do you know if this could be used to the same effect?

Comment: There is `@FilterJoinTable` which might be useful for your case, but it is hibernate specific. I have never used it because usually I avoid to use non-JPA standard stuff. If it works for you don't forget to post here your answer.

Comment: Cheers @jbx! I agree with avoiding non standard JPA. Will post my answer if it goes well!